# Combining aes_string or aes_q with multiple column labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to combine labels using multiple columns with a flexible variable name used to color the labels in ggplot2.

I am able to do this with a hard-coded variable name "ret_cumarpu_cluster" in aes like this:

```
ggplot(mergedata, aes(d2ret, d14cumarpu, col = ret_cumarpu_cluster)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_text(aes(label=paste(device_bucket, d90installs), col = ret_cumarpu_cluster), hjust = -.15, show.legend = FALSE)
```

generating this graph:

[image]

However, I would like to replace the hard coded string "ret_cumarpu_cluster" with a string object cluster_type for generating multiple graphs. I've tried various iterations of aes_q and aes_string, but none seem to work very well with pasting the two column names together to generate a label. Ideally, my code would look something like:

```
ggplot(mergedata, aes_string('d2ret', 'd14cumarpu', col = cluster_type)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_text(aes_q(label=(paste(device_bucket, d90installs)), col = as.name(cluster_type)), hjust = -.15)
```

As I said, I can't quite get the paste to work with aes_q or aes_string to allow me to have a multiple column label.

As a workaround, I could obviously create a new column in the data frame pasting those two strings together and just use that, but I was wondering if this was possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I can just add a ~ in front of the paste to get aes to recognize the names as columns.

```
ggplot(mergedata, aes_string('d2ret', 'd14cumarpu', col = cluster_type)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(aes_q(label=~(paste(device_bucket, d90installs)), col = as.name(cluster_type)), hjust = -.15, show.legend = FALSE)
```

Comment: Big props to you for recommending ~ in front of paste. This solved my problem. I haven't ever seen this use case for the ~, and, upon repeatedly googling in various ways, still can't find too many details explaining this use case.